# Using iFrames in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

Using `Angular 1.2+`, I'm trying to work out an "angular" way to load in an iFrame but I can't find any tutorials/any real discussion on this anywhere.

Basically, I have a search page which displays a list of links. Clicking a link should call a function in my controller which loads in data (possibly through the $http service?) to an iFrame while keeping the search results in view.

Here's some rudimentary code (I've never really used `iFrames` before so apologies if this is just totally wrong)

**View**

```
<div ng-controller="searchPage">
  <div ng-repeat='post in searchResults'>
    <a ng-click="itemDetail(post._infoLink)">Here's a link!</a>
  </div>
  <div class="detailView" ng-show="itemShown">
    <iframe ng-src="detailFrame"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.itemDetail = function(link){
  $scope.itemShown = true;
  $scope.busy = true;
  $http.get(link).success(function(data){
    $scope.busy = false;
    $scope.detailFrame = data;
  });
}
```

This code currently gives the error:

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load <url>. Origin http://localhost:5000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Something simple along these lines would be ideal. In the (attempted) example above, the search results would stay on the screen and get pushed into a sidebar, while the iFrame loads in an external site (on a different domain) into the bulk of the page.

How can this be achieved with Angular?

Extra caveat: The links to load into the iFrame are affiliate links so they'll often have a 'middleman' domain between them, e.g. the clicked-link will be `mydomain.com/cloakinglink` which redirects to `www.zanox.com/whatever` which then leads to the final site, `www.asos.com/whatever`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Due to [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), you can't get cross domain data by using XMLHttpRequest.

I'm not quite sure that what you really want to do.

You could try to bind iframe src attribute and clicked link url together to achieve the function if you just want iframe to show the web page which user cliked.

I wrote a simple example:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="searchPage">
  <div ng-repeat="page in searchResults">
      <a ng-click="itemDetail(page._infoLink)">{{page.label}}</a>
  </div>
  <iframe width="500" height="400" ng-src="{{detailFrame}}"></iframe>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function searchPage($scope){
  $scope.searchResults = [{label:"BBC",_infoLink:"http://www.bbc.co.uk/"},{label:"CNN",_infoLink:"http://edition.cnn.com/"}];

  $scope.itemDetail = function(link){
      $scope.detailFrame = link;
  };
}
```

Here is the [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/478wA/)

BTW... You could try server proxy if you really want to use XMLHttpRequest to grab data from 3-party web site and dump it to somewhere (You can't dump data to iframe src attribute! It only accepts the URL of web page).

Comment: your fiddle works but i don't understand, how come this works without using sce?? When I try this code it doesn't work

Answer (score 18):

As for AngularJS 1.2, there you should use the `$sce` service:

```
<iframe width="500" height="400" ng-src="{{detailFrame}}"></iframe>

$scope.detailFrame= $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Good luck...

Comment: Thank you so much. You save my times.

Answer (score 4):

Really struggled on just using regular dom to st iframe.src. Grr... Angular bends the light toward it.

```
 .state('nav.iframer', {
            url: '/iframer',
            templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/iframer.html',
            controller: function($rootScope, $sce){


                    var f = window.frames.iframer;//
                    this.frameUrl= $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://www.google.com");


            },

            controllerAs: 'framed'
        })
```

template:

```
<iframe name="iframer" width="900" height="900" ng-src="{{framed.frameUrl}}"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think some more clarification is needed along with another example.

$sce is a service that you MUST inject.  The reason it it is not included automatically is the overhead of performance,  you certainly WANT to be able to only load up services that you NEED.

$sce.trustasResourceURL thus is important

Example:

```
angular.module('tips')

.controller('TipsCtrl',

function ($http, $scope, UserService, $location, $routeParams, Categories, Tip, error, $sce) {  
    // various code  
    $scope.detailFrame = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://localhost:17308/Home/Index/2"); //hard coded
})
```

Then the IFrame:

```
<iframe ng-src="{{detailFrame}}" align="middle" width="1000" height="800" frameborder="0">
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```