# cannot load file in iframe getting error: Can't interpolate: {{file}}

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

I want to load a file in iFrame 
But i was getting an error like

```
angular.js:13642 Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{file}}
Error: [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.  URL: http://localhost:4000/api/uploads/574ed76718153dac202679b9_resume.pdf
```

For this i have found the solution that to use the below code in controller

```
$scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
    }
```

but the problem i m facing here is 
it is going on executing like a non-terminating loop, and the file is also not getting loaded.

here is my html

```
<div ng-class="{'col-xs-6': myVar=='something'}">
<div class="panel panel-default panel-height" ng-repeat="candidateInfo in aCandidateDetails track by $index" ng-click="fnInterviewView(candidateInfo.name)">
    <div class="panel-heading header-background">
        <div stop-watch time="xyz" name="candidateInfo.name" time-of-interview="candidateInfo.doi" class="stop-watch"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2"><a style="cursor:pointer" class="pull-right">{{candidateInfo.name}}</a></div>
            <div class="col-xs-offset-9"><a  style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="fnVar(candidateInfo.name,candidateInfo.filepath);$event.stopPropagation()" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="{{'#'+toggle}}">{{candidateInfo.name}} resume</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
angular.module('hrPortalApp')
.controller('candidateInterviewCtrl', function($scope, $state, $sce, getCandidateInterviewListService) {
    getCandidateInterviewListService.fnGetCandidateDetails(name).then(function(response) {
        $scope.aCandidateDetails = response;
        console.log(response);
        $scope.toggle = "accor"
    });
    $scope.fnVar = function(name, filepath) {
        $scope.file = "http://localhost:4000/" + filepath;
        $scope.checkVar = !$scope.checkVar;
        if ($scope.checkVar) {
            $scope.myVar = "something";
        } else {
            $scope.myVar = false;
        }
    };
    $scope.fnInterviewView = function(name) {
        $state.go('main.Topics', {
            "candidateDetails": $scope.aCandidateDetails,
            "name": name
        })
    };
    $scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
    }

});
```

I dont have an idea where i am going wrong

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is your iframe somewhere else in the html? Also, the html you included has one more opening <div> tag than closing and maybe the indentation is off?

Comment: i have div all closed and also my iframe is included there it self as i only need to load the file i gave src as my file path

Comment: Maybe i'm missing something but the <div ng-class="{'col-xs-6': myVar=='something'}"> div looks unclosed, unless everything after it is a child and should be indented, but then there still ought to be another </div> at the end of the markup, maybe just not included.

Comment: it is actually closed but i guessed i have not properly included @Andrew Clavin

Comment: I don't see where your iframe actually is, and where are you calling trustSrc?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're rerouting to the 'main.Topics' view on click of that first link as it propagates up to the div ng-click function.

This might help [Using iFrames in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828745/using-iframes-in-angularjs)